# Skaffold with helm fails to parse artifactOverrides

Tags: kubernetes-helm, skaffold

My skaffold.yaml

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: tons/whoami-mn
      jib: {}
  tagPolicy:
    gitCommit: {}
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: whoami-mn
        chartPath: ./k8s/helm/whoami-mn
        artifactOverrides:
          image.repository: tons/whoami-mn
```

The command

```
skaffold dev --port-forward --namespace whoami-mn
```

The error

```
parsing skaffold config: unable to parse config: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 11: field artifactOverrides not found in type v1.HelmRelease
```

Skaffold version: v1.13.1

Helm version: v3.3.0

Any idea why I'm getting the above error? Please let me know if I should post other parts of my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta6` was the key to it.

Answer (score 0):

In the future you can also try the `skaffold fix` command to find ways to update your schema automatically.